# Save User inputs and access them in later stages of session of Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

I currently have a list of selectInputs in a Rshiny dashboard that when combined create a data frame which is used for a later and very complex manipulation. I currently need to expand on the dashbaord to allow multiple submissions of userInputs. The goal is to have a method in which all of the userInputs submitted as data frames would be able to be combined at the end to then be manipulated. all of the data frames will have the same format with respect to names/length of columns but the number of rows might change. below is a image of the str of the idea of the dataframe.

example:
first submission is : df 1) x,y,z are column names

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCDdd.png)
 1. after submitted the selectInputs the user submitted are reset.

second submission is : df 2: x,y,z are column names

third submission is : df 3: x,y,z are column names

I want to access a combined data frame of (df 1, df2, df3) that is all of them stacked on one another. I want to add a new column, session, which saves the session # for the row in question when it was created.

I believe that the session feature of rshiny will be key to achieving the end result.   If there any other questions which already answer this please help direct me there.

Comment: did you take a look at `?reactiveValues`?

Comment: no but will take a deep dive right now

Comment: ?reactiveValue is not very descriptive

Comment: the descriptions of `reactiveValues` in the shiny docs are indeed pretty obscure. I womped up an small example of how to use it the way you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a toy program that does what you want using `reactiveValues`. I used a selectable character ID for the data instead of a fixed A,B,C:

```
library(shiny)
u <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Generate and accumulate data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("newrow","Number of new rows",3),
      selectInput("newid","Data Frame id",toupper(letters),"A"),
      actionButton("gennew","Generate new data"),
      actionButton("append","Append new data to total"),
      actionButton("clear","Clear total data")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h2("New data"),tableOutput("newdf"),
      h2("Total data"),tableOutput("totdf")
)))) 

zerodf <- data.frame(id=character(0),x=numeric(0),y=numeric(0),z=numeric(0))

s <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(newdf=zerodf,totdf=zerodf)

  observeEvent(input$gennew,{
    n <- input$newrow
    id <- input$newid
    rv$newdf <- data.frame(id=id,x=rnorm(n),y=rnorm(n),z=rnorm(n))
  })
  observeEvent(input$append,{ rv$totdf <- rbind(rv$totdf,rv$newdf)})
  observeEvent(input$clear,{  rv$totdf <- zerodf })

  output$newdf<-renderTable({  rv$newdf })
  output$totdf<-renderTable({  rv$totdf })
})
shinyApp(u,s)
```

A screen shot of it in action:

[image]

Comment: After a few hours of struggling and mix and matching other work i was getting somewhere similar to this. This is incredibly helpful and much much cleaner then my over engineered attempt. Thank you :)

Comment: Practice makes perfect :). Glad you tried it yourself first, that will make the learning go much deeper. By the way, you can upvote now :).

Comment: hahaha i know, was pretty pumped about that :). Thank you for supporting the community! I hope to be able to help others like you did me in the future. constant improvement is all that matters :)

Comment: I am sure you will.